# How to use stub() method with Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, stub

I'm learning about Mockito and I try to use stub() method. I have a simple code but it's not working because I get this error: "The method stub(int) is undefined for the type SpyTest". I want to know what dependency should I add in the pom file to use this stub() method? Thank you in advance!

This is the code:

```
package com.dgs.mockito;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class SpyTest {
    @Test
    void test() {
        List arrayListMock = mock(ArrayList.class);
        assertEquals(0, arrayListMock.size());
        stub(arrayListMock.size()).toReturn(5);
    }
}
```

And this is the pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.dgs.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-example</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
           <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
           <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
           <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
           <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
           <version>2.21.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
           <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
           <version>2.21.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I'm watching a tutorial from Udemy and and he are using this stub method. And if I try to manually add the import I get this error: "The import org.mockito.Mockito.stub cannot be resolved". I think I need to add another dependency in the pom file.

Comment: What is `stub` ?

Answer (score 5):

Here:

```
stub(arrayListMock.size()).toReturn(5);
```

You are calling a method that expects an int argument. But you didn't neither declare nor import such a method. The compiler has no idea what you are trying to do.

The correct way would be:

```
when(arrayListMock.size()).thenReturn(5);
```

( after importing `when()` from Mockito ).

The important thing to understand: there is no specific difference between "mocking" and "stubbing" with Mockito. You simply use `when(mock.someMethod())` to start a mocking specification. There is no `stub()` method in Mockito!

Then: please note that there is a difference between a **spy** and a **mock** in Mockito. A mock is a completely "virtual" object that has no relation whatsoever to the real code. A spy is more of an wrapper that Mockito puts "around" a real object of your class under test. Your test is named `SpyTest`, but it is **not** using a spy. If it would be using a spy, things are different.

Of course, the real real answer is: you never ever mock lists. You simply create a real list, and you fill it with the elements you need to be inside. Maybe the objects you put into the list are mocks, but there is *zero* need to mock lists itself.

To the contrary: that is *bad* practice. You try to *minimize* the amount of mocks you are using.

Answer (score -4):

Try

```
@Test
void test() {

    List arrayListMock = mock(ArrayList.class);
    doReturn(5).when(arrayListMock ).size();
    assertEquals(5, arrayListMock.size());

}
```

Comment: This post showed up in the Low Quality Posts review queue. It would be helpful to explain how this code answers the question.